# Counting frequency of values assigned to different types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, count

I apologize in advance for my poor description, I couldn't think of a way to word it better, but I'll try to explain it thoroughly.

Let's say that I have a table setup in this manner:

### Input Table

```
Itm Type
A   Apple
B   Orange
C   Apple
B   Grape
D   Peaches
B   Apple
C   Grapes
E   Apple
A   Apple
```

The goal is to produce a table showing each item (A, B, C, D, and E) with the total number of each type that was assigned to that item.

### Goal Output Table

```
Itm    Apple  Orange  Grape  Peaches    
A       2       0       0       0   
B       1       1       1       0
C       1       0       1       0
D       0       0       0       1
E       1       0       0       0
```

The query I'm using now displays a table where it seems to be summing up all of the types for all of the items and placing that value on each row.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Item, 
    ISNULL([Apple], 0) 'Apple', 
    ISNULL([Orange], 0) 'Orange', 
    ISNULL([Grapes], 0) 'Grapes', 
    ISNULL([Peaches], 0) 'Peaches'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Item, Type, count(*) 'ItemTypeCount'
    FROM 
        ItemTypes
    GROUP BY Item, Type
) AS T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ItemTypeCount) FOR Type IN ([Apple], [Orange], [Grapes], [Peaches])
) As PivotResults
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!  I'll have to learn more about this Pivot feature.

Answer (score 1):

### The query:

```
select Itm, Apple, Orange, Grape, Peaches
from items
pivot(count(Type) for Type in (Apple, Orange, Grape, Peaches)) p
```

Sample schema and data. You should **always** provide these when posting questions on StackOverflow.

```
create table items(Itm char(1), Type varchar(10));
insert items select
'A',   'Apple' union all select
'B',   'Orange' union all select
'C',   'Apple' union all select
'B',   'Grape' union all select
'D',   'Peaches' union all select
'B',   'Apple' union all select
'C',   'Grapes' union all select
'E',   'Apple' union all select
'A',   'Apple';
```

The result:

```
| ITM | APPLE | ORANGE | GRAPE | PEACHES |
------------------------------------------
|   A |     2 |      0 |     0 |       0 |
|   B |     1 |      1 |     1 |       0 |
|   C |     1 |      0 |     0 |       0 |
|   D |     0 |      0 |     0 |       1 |
|   E |     1 |      0 |     0 |       0 |
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/956ce/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this one

```
SELECT 
         ITEM 
         , SUM(APPLE) AS APPLE 
         , SUM(Grapes) AS Grapes
         ,SUM(Orange) AS Orange 
         , SUM(Peaches) AS Peaches
FROM(SELECT 
        ITEM 
        ,CASE WHEN TYPE = 'APPLE' THEN  COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS APPLE
        ,CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Grapes' THEN  COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS  Grapes
        ,CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Orange' THEN  COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS Orange
        ,CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Peaches' THEN  COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END AS Peaches 
    FROM ITEM
    GROUP BY ITEM , TYPE 
    ) AS A GROUP BY ITEM
```